# canvas.toDataURL() value changing even if canvas didn't change

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, base64

I've been studying and trying to write an application that takes whatever image is on an HTML5 canvas element and send it to clients. When trying to take the image using canvas.toDataURL(), compressing and sending it back to server, the client was sometimes displaying the image and sometimes not displaying what was sent. First I thought that it could be that the data was corrupted, but working on a local server and having 29/30 corrupted data didn't make sense to me, so I've tried to see what was going on and registered the length of the base64 image and noticed that it's length was changing, although the content of the canvas wasn't changing. Why is that happening? 
I wrote a simple page in which you can edit the canvas content by drawing on it that shows that happening:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Draw</title>
        <style>
            body{margin:0;}
        </style>
        <script>
            addEventListener("load", Load, false);

            var board = undefined;
            var ctx = undefined;

            var loaded = false;

            var mousehold = false;
            var mousex = 0;
            var mousey = 0;
            var lastx = 0;
            var lasty = 0;
            var firstclick = false;

            function Load(e)
            {
                loaded = true;
                board = document.getElementById("board");
                ctx = board.getContext("2d");

                board.width = window.innerWidth;
                board.height = window.innerHeight;

                addEventListener("mousedown", function(e)
                {
                    mousehold = true;
                }, false);

                addEventListener("mouseup", function(e)
                {
                    mousehold = false;
                    firstclick = false;
                }, false);

                addEventListener("mousemove", function(e)
                {
                    mousex = e.clientX;
                    mousey = e.clientY;

                    // if(mousehold == true) console.log(mousex + " " + mousey);
                }, false);

                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.lineWidth = 5;
                UpdateBoard();
            }

            function UpdateBoard()
            {
                if(mousehold == true)
                {
                    if(firstclick == false)
                    {
                        lastx = mousex;
                        lasty = mousey;
                        firstclick = true;
                    }

                    ctx.moveTo(lastx, lasty);
                    ctx.lineTo(mousex, mousey);
                    ctx.stroke();

                    lastx = mousex, lasty = mousey;
                }

                window.requestAnimationFrame(UpdateBoard);
            }

            function send()
            {
                var img = board.toDataURL();
                console.log(img.length);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="board"></canvas>
        <button style="right:10px;bottom:10px;position:fixed;z-index:999999;" onclick="send();">Send</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Clicking "send" button will log the base64 image length on console. If you draw something to the screen, the content of the canvas will obviously change, but if you stop drawing and click "send" button a few times (without touching canvas content) you'll see that it seems to be generating different base64 images. Why is that happening? Is it possible to prevent that from happening? My application needs to update content constantly (compressed, but I've tried it without compression and problem was the same).
To demonstrate the problem I've uploaded an image to imgur: [[http://imgur.com/a/iQ70T](https://imgur.com/a/iQ70T)](https://imgur.com/a/iQ70T) (ignore the typo in the image).
Thank you for your attention.

Comment: Post two examples of the encoded string that are different but result in the same image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why this happens is that you have attached all the event listeners to the `window` object and not the canvas (`mousedown`, the others can be on window) the `mousedown` will be registered also when you hit the send button.

This means the last path is redrawn for each frame since `mousehold` will be true, accumulating anti-aliasing pixels affecting the alpha channel, hence will change the bitmap.

Example fix (just attach the mousedown handler to canvas):

```js
addEventListener("load", Load, false);

var board = undefined;
var ctx = undefined;

var loaded = false;

var mousehold = false;
var mousex = 0;
var mousey = 0;
var lastx = 0;
var lasty = 0;
var firstclick = false;

function Load(e) {
  loaded = true;
  board = document.getElementById("board");
  ctx = board.getContext("2d");

  board.width = window.innerWidth;
  board.height = window.innerHeight;

  // this must be at canvas element
  board.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    mousehold = true;
  }, false);

  addEventListener("mouseup", function(e) {
    mousehold = false;
    firstclick = false;
  }, false);

  addEventListener("mousemove", function(e) {
    mousex = e.clientX;
    mousey = e.clientY;

    // if(mousehold == true) console.log(mousex + " " + mousey);
  }, false);

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = 5;
  UpdateBoard();
}

function UpdateBoard() {
  if (mousehold == true) {
    if (firstclick == false) {
      lastx = mousex;
      lasty = mousey;
      firstclick = true;
    }

    ctx.moveTo(lastx, lasty);
    ctx.lineTo(mousex, mousey);
    ctx.stroke();

    lastx = mousex, lasty = mousey;
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(UpdateBoard);
}

function send() {
  var img = board.toDataURL();
  console.log(img.length);
}
```

```css
body {margin:0}
```

```html
<canvas id="board"></canvas>
<button style="right:10px;bottom:10px;position:fixed;z-index:999999;" onclick="send();">Send</button>
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize such a thing. Feeling kinda stupid now. Thanks!

Comment: @FábioMorato no worries, it's easy to glance over things like that even for the most experienced devs.